# what do you call an instance of an interface?

Tags: interface

Ienumerable x=new classA();

I know you can't instantiate an interface. But would it be okay to call x an instance of Ienumerable? If not what is an easy way to address x while still conveying that its a variable of the type Ienumerable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - calling x an instance of Ienumerable is completely correct.

You could also say "x implements Ienumerable" or "x supports Ienumerable"